# Matching a number with the last n digits of another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of a pair of numbers e.g.:

```
1.45 4
0.73 17
0.201 18
509 24
0.55 21
```

Here the second number is the error of the first value.  In literature you would see it written as 1.45(4) for convenience when it should really be 1.45 +/- 0.04.  I would love to convert the second number to the 'real' error i.e. I want to convert the above list to:

```
1.45 0.04
0.73 0.17
0.201 0.018
509 24
0.55 0.21
```

My best success so far has been with the following function:

```
def gMatchError(fValue, fError):
  sExponent = -10
  while True:
    fFindDecimal = fValue*math.pow(10, sExponent)
    if fFindDecimal.is_integer():
      return fError / math.pow(10, sExponent)
    sExponent += 1
```

which iteratively multiplies the first value by 10^i until it is an integer.  When it is an integer, the error can then be divided by 10^i.

This works for all of the numbers listed above except for the last and returns 0.021.  I know that this is because of the nature of the way floats are stored in the memory i.e. from using .**repr**() I can see it checks to see if 55.000000001 is an integer which, of course, it is not.

I also tried to check with

```
if int(fFindDecimal) == int(fFindDecimal+0.9) and int(fFindDecimal) != 0:
  return (as above)
```

But this fails when there's a 0 in the middle e.g. in the 0.201 case.

Are there any alternatives that would work in all cases?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would 1.50 +/- 0.01 fit in your list? It looks like you have floats and ints in there, so it would get truncated to `1.5 1`, no? How are the numbers getting into the list? Are you reading them from a text file, for example?

Comment: Excellent point, it would be truncated such that the function would return  0.1 from 1.50(1), instead of the desired 0.01.  I hadn't considered this as I hadn't yet seen it appear in the list, but it can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've learned, decimal values are often not stored exactly as binary floats.  Instead, I recommend that you use the text version of the number as you read it in.  Perhaps something like this:

```
measure, error = input_line.split()
whole, frac = measure.split('.')
precision = len(frac)
error = float(error) / 10**precision

print measure, error
```

I've left a couple of inelegant points for you to handle:

- I quietly converted **error** from string to float ...
- ... while **measure** is still a string
- I ignored the case of an integer measure; the **whole, frac =** statement will fault.

However, I hope this will get you moving nicely toward a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def gMatchError(fValue, fError):
    exp = Decimal(fValue.as_tuple().exponent)
    return Decimal("10")**exp * fError
```

This also handles numbers like 0.500

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
def get_precision(num, precision):
    if num % 1:
        precision = precision * 10 ** -len(str(num).split('.')[1])
    return precision
```

To give

```
>>> get_precision(123.456,16)
0.016
>>> get_precision(123,16)
16
>>> get_precision(12231233.1,16)
1.6
```

Some explanations:

- The `num % 1` condition returns true if the number is not an integer, and so contains a decimal point
- `len(str(num).split('.')[1])` gives you the number of digits after the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['1.45 4',
'0.73 17',
'0.201 18',
'509 24',
'0.55 21']

for i,val in enumerate(a):
    temp = val.split(' ')
    if temp[0].find('.') != -1:
        dec_place = temp[0].find('.')
        tenth_power = temp[0][dec_place+1:]
        # divide the second number by 10 to the power of number of digits after the decimal
        # in the first number
        temp[1] = str(float(temp[1])/(10**(len(tenth_power))))
    # separate first and second value by space
    temp[0] +=' '
    # combine first and second value to a single string
    a[i] = ''.join(temp)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['1.45 0.04', '0.73 0.17', '0.201 0.018', '509 24', '0.55 0.21']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would determine the precision from the string representation of the first number (for example, you cannot distinguish 10.0 from 10.00 from the floating point variable).  With regular expressions, you can obtain the different elements with groups.

```
VALUES = (
  '1.45 4',
  '0.73 17',
  '0.201 18',
  '509 24',
  '0.55 21',
)

import re
REGEX = re.compile( r"(\d+(\.(\d+))?)\s(\d+)" )

for v in VALUES:
  m = REGEX.match(v)
  if m.group(3) is not None:
    nd = len(m.group(3))   # nb of decimals in first number          
    d = 0.1 ** nd
    n2 = float(m.group(4)) * d
    print "{n1} {n2:{nd}}".format(n1=m.group(1), n2=n2, nd=nd)
  else:
    print v
```

which prints

```
1.45 0.04
0.73 0.17
0.201 0.018
509 24
0.55 0.21
```